# How to hide a button after clicked in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering how to hide my start button after being clicked so that If the user accidentally was clicker happy they wouldn't hit the button causing more bubbles to appear on screen. Below is a snippet of the coding using Python 3.3:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random

    from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

    class BFrame:

        def __init__(self, root, name):
            self.name = name
            root.title("Math Bubbles")
            self.bubbles = {} # this will hold bubbles ids, positions and velocities
            self.score = 0
            Button(root, text="Start", width=8, bg="Pink", command=self.make_bubbles).pack() # This button starts the game, making the bubbles move across the screen
            Button(root, text="Quit", width=8, bg="Yellow",command=quit).pack()
            self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg='#afeeee')
            self.canvas.create_text(400, 30, fill="darkblue", font="Times 20 italic bold", text="Click the bubbles that are answers in the two times tables.")
            #Shows score at beginning of the game
            self.current_score = self.canvas.create_text(200, 60, fill="darkblue", font="Times 15 italic bold", text="Your score is: 0")
            self.canvas.pack()



def make_bubbles(self):
    for each_no in range(1, 21):
        xval = random.randint(5, 765)
        yval = random.randint(5, 615)
        COLOURS = ('#00ff7f', '#ffff00', '#ee82ee', '#ff69b4', '#fff0f5') # CAPS represents a constant variable
        colour = random.choice(COLOURS) # This picks a colour randomly
        oval_id = self.canvas.create_oval(xval, yval, xval + 60, yval + 60,fill=colour, outline="#000000", width=5, tags="bubble")
        text_id = self.canvas.create_text(xval + 30, yval + 30, text=each_no, tags="bubble")
        self.canvas.tag_bind("bubble", "<Button-1>", lambda x: self.click(x))
        self.bubbles[oval_id] = (xval, yval, 0, 0, each_no, text_id) # add bubbles to dictionary

        def click(self, event):
            if self.canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
                item_uid = event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
                is_even = False
                try: # clicked oval
                    self.bubbles[item_uid]
                except KeyError: # clicked oval
                    for key, value in self.bubbles.iteritems():
                        if item_uid == value[5]: # comparing to text_id
                            if value[4] % 2 == 0:
                                is_even = True
                            self.canvas.delete(key) # deleting oval
                            self.canvas.delete(item_uid) # deleting text
                else:
                    if self.bubbles[item_uid][4] % 2 == 0:
                        is_even = True
                    self.canvas.delete(item_uid) # deleting oval
                    self.canvas.delete(self.bubbles[item_uid][5]) # deleting text

                if is_even:
                    self.score += 1
                else:
                    self.score -= 1
                    showinfo("Oh no!", "%s! You clicked the wrong bubble, please start again." % self.name)

                if self.score == 10:
                    #Tells user You won! if score is 10
                    showinfo("Winner", "You won %s!" % self.name)


            self.canvas.delete(self.current_score)
            #Shows updated score on canvas
            self.current_score = self.canvas.create_text(200, 60, fill="darkblue", font="Times 15 italic bold", text="Your score is: %s"%self.score)
```

Comment: You could have the button's handler change the button's state to `DISABLED`

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to hide it, or are you asking a broader question about how to prevent the user from clicking on it at the wrong time?

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the state of the button in the handler:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = tk.Button(master, text='foo', command=self.switch_state)
        self.b.pack()
    def switch_state(self):
        print("Called")
        self.b['state'] = tk.DISABLED

master = tk.Tk()
a = App()
master.mainloop()
```

(python2.7 code, but it should translate to py3k pretty easily).

Answer (score -1):

## python 3.7

```
from tkinter import *

def toggle():
   locx, locy = label.winfo_x(), label.winfo_y()
   label.place(x=-locx,y=-locy)

master = Tk()
master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (500,500))
label=Label(master,text="Lebel : Hide Me")
label.place(x=50,y=20)
btn=Button(text="Toggle",command=toggle)
btn.place(x=50,y=50)
mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it had a description of why this works. Also, this ides the label but the question was asking how to hide the button.