# hide a button after clicking it

Tags: python, tkinter, button, python-3.9

I want to hide a button after the user clicks it how do I do it?

I've tried

`def hide(widget):`
`widget.pack_forget()`
`btn2 = Button(master, text="no", command=lambda: hide(btn2))`
`btn2.place(x=200, y=70)`

the program runs but the button doesn't hide

Comment: Hi, I think your question has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473775/how-to-hide-a-button-after-clicked-in-python

Comment: You use `.place()` on the button, but why do you use `.pack_forget()` inside `hide()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.place()` to put the button on the window you have to use `.place_forget()` to remove it:

```py
# create the button
btn2 = Button(master, text="no", command=btn2.place_forget)

# place the button
btn2.place(x=200, y=70)

# remove the button
btn2.place_forget()
```